# Why am I getting ZZZ output for my Verilog cordic code?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, rtl, cordic

```
module Cordic_multiplier_16bit(Xin,Yin,Zin,clk,Xn,Yn,Zn); 
input [15:0]Xin,Yin,Zin;  
output reg [15:0]Xn = 16'b0,Yn= 16'b0,Zn= 16'b0; 
input clk; 
wire [15:0]X,Y,Z; 

//output variables for each stage  
wire[15:0]w1,w4,w7,w10,w13,w16,w19,w22,w25,w28,w31,w34,w37,w40,w43,w46; 
wire[15:0]w2,w5,w8,w11,w14,w17,w20,w23,w26,w29,w32,w35,w38,w41,w44,w47;
wire[15:0]w3,w6,w9,w12,w15,w18,w21,w24,w27,w30,w33,w36,w39,w42,w45,w48;

wire[15:0]R1,R4,R7,R10,R13,R16,R19,R22,R25,R28,R31,R34,R37,R40,R43,R46; 
wire[15:0]R2,R5,R8,R11,R14,R17,R20,R23,R26,R29,R32,R35,R38,R41,R44,R47;
wire[15:0]R3,R6,R9,R12,R15,R18,R21,R24,R27,R30,R33,R36,R39,R42,R45,R48;

 //LUT table 
reg [15:0]LUT1=16'b0001000110010011; 
reg [15:0]LUT2=16'b0000100000101100; 
reg [15:0]LUT3=16'b0000010000000100; 
reg [15:0]LUT4=16'b0000001000000000; 
reg [15:0]LUT5=16'b0000000100000000; 
reg [15:0]LUT6=16'b0000000010000000; 
reg [15:0]LUT7=16'b0000000001000000; 
reg [15:0]LUT8=16'b0000000000100000; 
reg [15:0]LUT9=16'b0000000000010000; 
reg [15:0]LUT10=16'b0000000000001000; 
reg [15:0]LUT11=16'b0000000000000100; 
reg [15:0]LUT12=16'b0000000000000010; 
reg [15:0]LUT13=16'b0000000000000001; 
reg [15:0]LUT14=16'b0000000000000001; 
 
reg_16bit REG01(X,Xin,clk); 
reg_16bit REG02(Y,Yin,clk);//storing Xin,Yin,Zin values in X,Y,Z  
reg_16bit REG03(Z,Zin,clk); 

//1st stage 
adder_sub_block ASB1(Y[15:0],X[15:0],~Y[15],w1); 
reg_16bit REG1(R1,w1,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB2(Y[15:0],X[15:0],~Y[15],w2); 
reg_16bit REG2(R2,w2,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB3(Z[15:0],LUT1,Y[15],w3); 
reg_16bit REG3(R3,w3,clk); 

//2nd stage 
adder_sub_block ASB4(R1,Y[15:0]>>>1,~R2[15],w4); 
reg_16bit REG4(R4,w4,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB5(R2,X[15:0]>>>1,~R2[15],w5); 
reg_16bit REG5(R5,w5,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB6(R3[15:0],LUT2,R2[15],w6); 
reg_16bit REG6(R6,w6,clk); 

//3rd stage 
adder_sub_block ASB7(R4,Y[15:0]>>>2,~R5[15],w7); 
reg_16bit REG7(R7,w7,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB8(R5,X[15:0]>>>2,~R5[15],w8); 
reg_16bit REG8(R8,w8,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB9(R6[15:0],LUT3,R5[15],w9); 
reg_16bit REG9(R9,w9,clk); 

//4th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB10(R7,Y[15:0]>>>3,~R8[15],w10); 
reg_16bit REG10(R10,w10,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB11(R8,X[15:0]>>>3,~R8[15],w11); 
reg_16bit REG11(R11,w11,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB12(R9[15:0],LUT4,R8[15],w12); 
reg_16bit REG12(R12,w12,clk); 

//5th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB13(R10,Y[15:0]>>>4,~R11[15],w13); 
reg_16bit REG13(R13,w13,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB14(R14,X[15:0]>>>4,~R11[15],w14); 
reg_16bit REG14(R14,w14,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB15(R15[15:0],LUT4,R11[15],w15); 
reg_16bit REG15(R15,w15,clk);

//6th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB16(R16,Y[15:0]>>>5,~R14[15],w16); 
reg_16bit REG16(R16,w16,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB17(R17,X[15:0]>>>5,~R14[15],w17); 
reg_16bit REG17(R17,w17,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB18(R18[15:0],LUT5,R11[15],w18); 
reg_16bit REG18(R18,w18,clk); 

//7th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB19(R19,Y[15:0]>>>6,~R17[15],w19); 
reg_16bit REG19(R19,w19,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB20(R20,X[15:0]>>>6,~R17[15],w20); 
reg_16bit REG20(R20,w20,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB21(R21[15:0],LUT6,R17[15],w21); 
reg_16bit REG21(R21,w21,clk); 

//8th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB22(R22,Y[15:0]>>>7,~R20[15],w22); 
reg_16bit REG22(R22,w22,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB23(R23,X[15:0]>>>7,~R20[15],w23); 
reg_16bit REG23(R23,w23,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB24(R24[15:0],LUT7,R20[15],w24); 
reg_16bit REG24(R24,w24,clk); 
 
//9th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB25(R25,Y[15:0]>>>8,~R23[15],w25); 
reg_16bit REG25(R25,w25,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB26(R26,X[15:0]>>>8,~R23[15],w26); 
reg_16bit REG26(R26,w26,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB27(R27[15:0],LUT8,R23[15],w27); 
reg_16bit REG27(R27,w27,clk); 

//10th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB28(R28,Y[15:0]>>>9,~R26[15],w28); 
reg_16bit REG28(R28,w28,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB29(R29,X[15:0]>>>9,~R26[15],w29); 
reg_16bit REG29(R29,w29,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB30(R30[15:0],LUT9,R26[15],w30); 
reg_16bit REG30(R30,w30,clk);

//11th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB31(R31,Y[15:0]>>>10,~R29[15],w31); 
reg_16bit REG31(R31,w31,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB32(R32,X[15:0]>>>10,~R29[15],w32); 
reg_16bit REG32(R32,w32,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB33(R33[15:0],LUT10,R29[15],w33); 
reg_16bit REG33(R33,w33,clk); 

//12th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB34(R34,Y[15:0]>>>11,~R32[15],w34); 
reg_16bit REG34(R34,w34,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB35(R35,X[15:0]>>>11,~R32[15],w35); 
reg_16bit REG35(R35,w35,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB36(R36[15:0],LUT11,R32[15],w36); 
reg_16bit REG36(R36,w36,clk);  

//13th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB37(R37,Y[15:0]>>>12,~R35[15],w37); 
reg_16bit REG37(R37,w37,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB38(R38,X[15:0]>>>12,~R35[15],w38); 
reg_16bit REG38(R38,w38,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB39(R39[15:0],LUT12,R35[15],w39); 
reg_16bit REG39(R39,w39,clk); 

//14th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB40(R40,Y[15:0]>>>13,~R38[15],w40); 
reg_16bit REG40(R40,w40,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB41(R41,X[15:0]>>>13,~R38[15],w41); 
reg_16bit REG41(R41,w41,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB42(R42[15:0],LUT13,R38[15],w42); 
reg_16bit REG42(R42,w42,clk);

//15th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB43(R43,Y[15:0]>>>14,~R41[15],w43); 
reg_16bit REG43(R43,w43,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB44(R44,X[15:0]>>>14,~R41[15],w44); 
reg_16bit REG44(R44,w44,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB45(R45[15:0],LUT13,R41[15],w45); 
reg_16bit REG45(R45,w45,clk); 

//16th stage 
adder_sub_block ASB46(R46,Y[15:0]>>>15,~R44[15],w46); 
reg_16bit REG46(R46,w46,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB47(R47,X[15:0]>>>15,~R44[15],w47); 
reg_16bit REG47(R47,w47,clk); 
adder_sub_block ASB48(R48[15:0],LUT14,R44[15],w48); 
reg_16bit REG48(R48,w48,clk); 
endmodule 

//Pipeline Register 
module reg_16bit(out,in,clk); 
input clk; 
input [15:0]in; 
output reg [15:0]out; 
always@(posedge clk) 
begin 
out<=in; 
end 
endmodule 

module adder_sub_block(A,B,Cin,out); 
input [15:0]A,B; 
input Cin; 
output reg [15:0]out; 
always@(Cin) 
case(Cin) 
1:out=A-B; 
0:out=A+B; 
endcase 
endmodule



module stimulus;
reg [15:0] X, Y,Z;
wire [15:0] X_out, Y_out, Z_out;
reg clk;
initial
    $monitor($time, "X_out = %b, Y_out = %b, Z_out = %b",X_out, Y_out, Z_out);

  initial 
  begin 
    clk <= 1'b0;
    #2000 $finish;
  end

  always #30 clk = ~clk;
  
  initial 
  begin 
     X <= 33; Y <= 31; Z<=0;  
  end    
endmodule
```

here is the output for the above code:

```
0X_out = zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, Y_out = zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, Z_out = zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
main.v:199: $finish called at 2000 (1s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `Z` at outputs because you have not instantiated your module `Cordic_multiplier_16bit` in the testbench `stimulus`. In your current `stimulus`, `X_out`, `Y_out` and `Z_out` are just a couple of wires that are not connected and are undriven and that is the root cause of `Z`.

You are generating the inputs in the testbench but you are not feeding those to your `Cordic_multiplier_16bit` in the testbench. Here is what you should do in the testbench:

```
module stimulus;
    reg [15:0] X, Y,Z;
    wire [15:0] X_out, Y_out, Z_out;
    reg clk;
    initial
        $monitor($time, "X_out = %b, Y_out = %b, Z_out = %b",X_out, Y_out, Z_out);

  initial 
  begin 
    clk <= 1'b0;
    #2000 $finish;
  end

  always #30 clk = ~clk;
  
  initial 
  begin 
     X <= 33; Y <= 31; Z<=0;  
  end    
  
  
  Cordic_multiplier_16bit DUT(
      .Xin(X),
      .Yin(Y),
      .Zin(Z),
      .clk(clk),
      .Xn(X_out),
      .Yn(Y_out),
      .Zn(Z_out)
  ); 
 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `z` for your output because the signals that you monitored have no drivers.

You declared these signals as type `wire` in the `stimulus` module, and wires have the default value of `z` in Verilog (high impedance).  You need to add an instance of the top-level design in the testbench module:

```
module stimulus;
reg  [15:0] X, Y, Z;
wire [15:0] X_out, Y_out, Z_out;
reg clk;

Cordic_multiplier_16bit dut (
    .Xin  (X),
    .Yin  (Y),
    .Zin  (Z),
    .clk  (clk),
    .Xn   (X_out),
    .Yn   (Y_out),
    .Zn   (Z_out)
);

initial begin 
    $monitor($time, " X_out = %b, Y_out = %b, Z_out = %b", X_out, Y_out, Z_out);
    clk = 0;
    X = 33;
    Y = 31;
    Z = 0;  
    #2000 $finish;
end

always #30 clk = ~clk;

endmodule
```

This is the new output, showing that the `z` values are now resolved to known values:

```
               0 X_out = 0000000000000000, Y_out = 0000000000000000, Z_out = 0000000000000000
```

I also combined the 3 `initial` blocks into one for simplicity.  I added a space after `$time` in the `$monitor` statement for clarity.